# Using Sterling's Formula to prove log(n!) = Θ(nlogn)

Tags: proof-explanation

I'm reviewing a proof [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PIlt.png)

and I'm having trouble understanding how to get to step 1. I know Sterlings formula is sqrt(2pi*n) * (n/e)^n
but where did they get (1 + o(1/n) from in step 1?

Comment: It appears to be part of the specific form of Stirling's formula they are quoting.

Comment: Look at the bottom of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation#Derivation - although using Stirling is a complete overkill to establish this estimate.